# "Restrict who can push to this branch" is not available anymore

Tags: github

I clearly remember that option existing in the Branch Protection settings, and now I don't see it anymore on GitHub. Is it a matter of project setup, or maybe GH removed the feature?

Answer (score 3):

The feature still exist! Working fine for me.

Please Check the link for more information.

[Enabling GitHub branch restriction](https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/)

Comment: Ah! Mother of all motherboards!! Your link says it: the feature exists only if the repo belongs to an organization. And my repo is a personal one.

Comment: @mircealungu did you find a way to do it for a personal one ?